# How to rewrite rules in htacess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to write rules to redirect to following pages using .htaccess file.I am new to this.
How I suppose to do it?

Facebook: test.com/FB (redirects to https://www.facebook.com/test.etutors)
Twitter: test.com/Twitter (redirects to https://twitter.com/test)

Comment: Show something that you tried/researched for the problem!

Comment: RewriteRule ^http://test.com/FB$ https://www.facebook.com/test.etutors [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempted rule won't work because `RewriteRule` only matches request URI not the domain part. Have your rules like this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^FB/?$ https://www.facebook.com/test.etutors [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Twitter/?$ https://twitter.com/test [L,NC,R=301]
```

**PS:** Since you're a new user I suggest you to show your code by editing your question rather than in comments.

Comment: Is `L` needed when we're redirecting the user?

Comment: I have always used it in conjunction with `R`. I will do some testing on my side if behavior is same without `L` also.

Comment: The docs mention "_You will almost always want to use `[R]` in conjunction with `[L]` (that is, use `[R,L]`) because on its own, the `[R]` flag prepends `http://thishost[:thisport]` to the URI, but then passes this on to the next rule in the ruleset, which can often result in 'Invalid URI in request' warnings_". Since, here the user is redirected to a different domain, is the `L` flag necessary?